# How does array.filter work with JSON.stringify in this specific instance?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this code of JavaScript that I don’t actually understand, specifically this line:

```
const res = arr.filter(item => !store.has(JSON.stringify(item)) ? store.add(JSON.stringify(item)) : false);
```

How does filter work here to eliminate the duplicates in [[1,2,3], [1,2,3]] to [[1,2,3]]?

Full snippet:

```
function storeArr(arr) {
 const store = new Set();
 const res = arr.filter(item => !store.has(JSON.stringify(item)) ? store.add(JSON.stringify(item)) : false);
 return res // [[1,2,3]]
}
storeArr([[1,2,3], [1,2,3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

The storeArr function is filtering the pased-in array 'arr' (of arrays) by checking to see if the Set object called 'store' does not have a match for each element (a sub-array).

While at the same time it's checking, it is also either adding the element to the 'store' object or returning false.

So the first [1,2,3] is added to 'store' and the presence of that element in 'store' keeps the second one from being added.

The filtered array is what is returned by the function.

The sub-arrays have to be exactly the same for them to be filtered out, e.g. storeArr([[1,2,3], [1,2,4]]) => [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 4 ] ]

Comment: res here is the filtered version of the passed in array. However, what I don't understand is, the filter function adds to the set, but how does it filter out unique values for the res array?

Comment: The filter function only adds to the Set if store does not have a JSON stringifyed item ( !store.has(JSON.stringify(item))), if it does have a JSON stringyfied item then the filter function returns false ( : false) in the Conditional (ternary) operator. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator